# How to mark an answer for a question I've abandoned?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

Sometimes I'll ask a question about something and then abandon the thing I was doing without ever finding out if a proposed solution works.

For instance, [I had a problem with the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17024538) and got a huge amount of advice on it. But I was pulled off the project just after posting my question and never had the opportunity to try any of the answers to see if they work, and so I have no meaningful way to mark an answer as correct.

I really want to give someone credit for their answer, but I just don't know which answers really would have solved my problem. What should I do about this?

Answer (score 42):

If you don't know, you don't know, and pretending you do doesn't help anyone.

Just remember that there's no obligation to accept *any* answer.

Comment: Indeed, the tooltip over the accept checkmark says: "Click to accept this answer **because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution**" - in this case neither of those things happened.

Comment: You could possibly update the original question, stating you did not have the opportunity to test any of the things and that that is why you did not accept any answers, to prevent others from thinking that none of them are any good to try, I suppose?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I settled for a brief comment on the original question.

Comment: Agree, mostly. I mean, try _not_ to abandon it: if you can, on your own time, it's nice to figure out which solution worked anyway. If you cannot reproduce the scenario sufficiently outside of a business domain within which you no longer reside, then you obviously can't do that .... but then it seems unlikely that the question was on topic in the first place. So.

Comment: @spoorlezer: No, such information does not belong in a question. In a comment under the question, _maybe_.